# Adding dynamic parent category sub category to db

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to design a database schema where there are multiple parent category, and each parent category has multiple sub category, in turn those sub categories can have another sub category with different attributes from the former ones, i want to achieve this dynamically as per user choice where an user has the liberty to add a parent category and add one or more sub category to the parent category to suit his needs, and in turn those sub category have another sub category added by the user in future
This is my sample schema:

Category table

| Id | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Books |
| 2 | Toys |

Sub Category table

| Id | CategoryId | SubCategory | SubCategoryId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Schoolbooks | 20001 |
| 2 | 2 | Action toys | 20002 |

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance!!
Kindly help me as to how can I achieve the above said pattern

Comment: Do you have a question?  If so, you should ask one.

Comment: Alright, sorry for the inconvenience, would you be kind enough to suggest me a solution for the above said pattern?